# Populate triple select help needed

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dropdown list that triggers a change event that populates a second select list via jquery and php. What I need to do is, when the first event is triggered, populate dropdown 2 with the callback data and also populate dropdown 3 with the value of dropdown 2. I need to query 2 tables company_com and departments which I can do using a JOIN but not sure how to return the data based on the query.

I have posted the code I am currently using and would be grateful for any help with this as I am not sure what direction to go. Many thanks.

jQuery change event code

```
$(function() {
  $("#dstr_dept").change(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxDstrsubcat.php?dstrdept=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#box_dstr").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#box_dstr").trigger("chosen:updated"); 
      });
    });
  });
});
```

php code

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>

<?php
    include('../Connections/domain.php');

    $dstrdept = $_GET['cltdstrdept'];
    $customer = $_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr'];

    mysql_select_db($database_domain, $domain);
    $query = "SELECT name FROM departments WHERE code = '".$dstrdept."' ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    echo "<script type=text/javascript>\n";
    echo "$(function() {\n";
    echo "$(\".noBdstrBoxes\").html('')\n";
    echo "$('#dstr_dept').attr('data-placeholder', \"Choose your dept...\").prop('disabled', false)\n";
    //echo "$(\"#box_dstr\").prop('disabled', false)\n";
    //echo "$('#Frtv').show()\n";
    echo "});\n";
    echo "</script>\n";

    // This returns the data of departments
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";
    }    

    } else {

    echo "<script type=text/javascript>\n";
    echo "$(function() {\n";
    echo "$('.noBdstrBoxes').html('ERROR: There are no boxes to destroy in that dept. Please select another.').css({\"color\":\"red\", \"margin\": \"-6px 0 10px 22px\", \"font-size\": \"12px\", \"font-family\": \"Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif\"})\n";
    echo "$('#box_dstr').attr('data-placeholder', \"No boxes to display...\").prop('disabled', true)\n";
    echo "});\n";
    echo "</script>\n";

    //echo "<option value='No boxes in that dept'>No boxes in that dept</option>";

    }
?>
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="fieldset">
          <h1><span>Select a Customer</span></h1>
          <p>
            <select data-placeholder="Choose a customer..." class="chosen-select" style="width:250px;" name="dstr_customer" id="dstr_customer">
              <option value=""></option>
                <option value="DEMO">DEMO</option>
                <option value="DEMO2">DEMO2</option>
                <option value="DEMO3">DEMO2</option>
                <option value="DEMO4">DEMO2</option>
            </select>
            <span></span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="margin-left:10px;" class="tooltip" title="Please select a dept where the box to be destroyed is stored.">Help</a>
          </p>
        </div>

<div class="fieldset">
          <h1><span>Select a Department</span></h1>
          <p>
            <select data-placeholder="Choose a dept..." class="chosen-select" style="width:250px;" name="dstr_dept" id="dstr_dept">
              <option value=""></option>

            </select>
            <span></span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="margin-left:10px;" class="tooltip" title="Please select a dept where the box to be destroyed is stored.">Help</a>
          </p>
        </div>

<div class="fieldset">
          <h1><span>Select an Address</span></h1>
          <p>
            <select data-placeholder="Choose an address..." class="chosen-select" style="width:250px;" name="dstr_address" id="dstr_address">
              <option value=""></option>

            </select>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

<div class="fieldset">
          <h1><span>Select Your Box(es)</span></h1>
          <p>
            <select data-placeholder="Choose your box(es)..." class="chosen-select" name="box_dstr[]" id="box_dstr" multiple required="required">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
            <span></span>
            <a style="margin-left: 12px;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" title="Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 20 boxes per submission.<br />.<br />You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection">Help</a>
          </p>
          <div class="noBdstrBoxes"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use php to resubmit the page to the server and then use the value from the first select box to use in your queries to populate the next two select boxes.

Or you could use AJAX to do the same thing without reloading the page.  But then you will have to use javascript to change the 2 select boxes on the page.

Comment: Do you have an example. I can follow better with an example. Thanks

Comment: I would need more information to help.  What I was thinking was when the first dropdown is selected.  You would use a form tag to send the data back to your php scripts, passing in the value for customer.  Then run one or two queries and pass that data back to your html and then loop through the results to build the new drop down boxes.